# How to get Full rows for groupby function for the following problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtrCa.png)

I am executing the following code to groupby similar items, take SUM and then average it with similar (groupby) items. The instruction works fine but i need my output with full rows, my current output provides only one item of *ORIGIN_AIRPORT* against all *DESTINATION_AIRPORT*. It should be ANC for SEA as well.
I hope anyone got my point.
`df=df.groupby(['ORIGIN_AIRPORT', 'DESTINATION_AIRPORT']).agg({'SUM': np.average})`

Comment: Please provide an example dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try:

```
df=df.groupby(['ORIGIN_AIRPORT', 'DESTINATION_AIRPORT']).agg({'SUM': np.average}).reset_index()
```

add [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) at the end of the query.